AlamoFire streamRequest returning too much JSON data in each chunk and therefore fails to decode the json, but works fine on the localhost server
On the server side:
I have a fastapi running in a docker container. The server has an endpoint that returns a FastAPI StreamingResponse with a python generator as the response, something like this:
@router.post("/json/stream", summary="Open a stream of json objects to be collected")
def stream_json_as_received(opt_request: AllJsonRequest):

    # makes a call to a data provider

    def generate_json_data(args):

        # do some processing on the received data
        
        yield json.dumps(chunked_json_dict) + '\n'

        # start the generator again if there are more
        if "next_url" in json_response:
            yield from generate_json_data(args)
        elif "next_url" not in json_response:
            print("All json chunks has been retrieved")
            pass
   
   return StreamingResponse(generate_json_data(args), media_type="application/x-ndjson"

The idea is to display the Json objects on the client as they are yielded by the StreamingResponse.
On the client side:
So heres where the problem starts. On my ios client (SwiftUI) I am attempting to consume this endpoint with the AlamoFire library like so:
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Alamofire

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var jsonObjects: [AllJsonsStream] = []

    fileprivate lazy var alamoSession: Session = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
        configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
        return Alamofire.Session(configuration: configuration /*, interceptor: interceptor*/)
    }()

    
    fileprivate func alamofireChunked () {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mydockerfastapiurl/json/stream")
        else {
            return
        }
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "arg1": val1
        ]
        
        
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("chunked", forHTTPHeaderField: "transfer-encoding")
        print(request.headers)
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, jsonObjects: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR")
        }

        alamoSession.streamRequest(request).validate().responseStream { response in
            if let data = response.value {
                print("received \(data.count) bytes")
                if data.count > 0 {
                    // process received data here
                    print("data:", data.description)
                    
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    
                    do {
                        try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                        let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(AllJsonsStream.self, from:data)
                        print("Decoded:", decodedResponse)
                        self.jsonObjects.append(decodedResponse)
                        } catch let error {
                            print(error)
                     }
                }
            } else {
                switch response.event {
                case .complete( _):
                    // perform any post processing here
                    print("stream is finished")
                    print("response:", response.result)
                    break;
                default:
                    print("default...")
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    private var urlString = ""
    var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                viewModel.alamofireChunked()
            } label: {
                Text("Fetch stream")
            }
            
        }
    }
}


When I run this sample project, I get a series of these errors: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0} from each chunk returned.
This obviously points to the error being that the chunked responses are not proper json format and would then obviously not be able to serialize those into the AllJsonStreams object.
This lead me to change the '.responseStream' -> '.responseStreamString' to see what the actual responses were from the endpoint and why this error was happening. I printed out each chunk as it came in, and I found that each response was bringing back: the first yielded json AND SOME of the next yielded json, cut off at a random point, kind of like this:
'{"key1": "value1"}, {"Key2": "va'

Obviously this is not proper JSON, and further, I was very confused as to why it was bringing back more data than just the 1 properly yielded json object in each chunk.
I then went to validate that the fastAPI endpoint was properly returning good json objects on each yield. I tested the response in Postman and the SwaggerUI for my fastAPI server and both responses looked good and proper.
Here's where it gets a little funky.
I then had the idea to run my fastAPI server locally and test all the same stuff, again it all looked good. So i plugged in the localhost url to my Swift project "http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/stream" and to my complete surprise, each chunk had exactly the correct json (no extra, half-json objects) and everything serialized perfectly fine. The only thing that changed was switching from the url pointing to a docker container to a url pointing to my localhost version of the server.
To further confuse me, our android team can consume this endpoint perfectly fine from the docker container server.
The only reason I could think of that it would work properly on the localhost but not from the container was the speed of the request being faster or something is wrong in the docker configuration (which still doesn't make total sense as the android version works fine)
I have tried looking at alamo-fire docs for hours trying to find a reason in the library that this could be happening (for reference, before using alamo fire, we tried a similar setup just using the Combine library and got similar results).
I tried adding a CustomSerializer with my decodable data type, same error. I tried changing the content-type header to 'application/x-ndjson' like the StreamingResponse returns and tried changing the media_type in the python generator to things like 'text/event-stream', or 'application/json', same error.
Becuase of my idea that the speed of the request was messing it up somehow, I tried changing the Swift session configuration to allow for a bigger timeoutIntervalForRequest, same Error.
Could this be a problem that my fastAPI endpoint is a POST instead of a GET?
At this point I am completely lost, as is my entire team, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Alamofire's DataStreamRequest intentionally leaves buffering and chunking up to the consumer, for exactly this reason. Raw HTTP streaming gives you no (well, little) control over the chunking of data on the client side, and URLSession has nothing to help. So there are manifold standards and approaches to chunking and buffering that could be taken.
However, it looks like you might be using a standard response type you can use to manually parse the incoming data.  According to the application/x-ndjson standard, each object will be separated by a newline, which makes the parsing relatively trivial. You need to build a buffering layer on top of DataStreamRequest that then splits and parses the JSON after newlines.
In general you'll want to:

Store received Data and append each incoming chuck.
Once appended, see if there's a newline in the stored chunk.


If so, remove the first prefix of Data up to and including the newline. Parse that Data as JSON.
If not, continue appending.


Call your completion handler / publisher / async stream with the result of the JSON parsing for any chunks you try to parse.

You'll want to be careful about maximum buffer sizes and back pressure (too much data may queue up too much buffering and parsing work), but those depend on your use case.
Once I get Alamofire's WebSocketRequest more production-ready, I'd recommend switching to a websocket, which handles all of this for you.
